# How can I have infinite clicks on my button because after i click the button it does not work anymore

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //this will make it appear
    function showPicture() {
      var sourceOfPicture = "img/tierlist.jpg";
      var img = document.getElementById('tierlist')
      img.src = sourceOfPicture.replace('90x90', '225x225');
      img.style.display = "block";
    } 

    // this will remove the picture
    function removePicture() {
      var image_x = document.getElementById('tierlist');
      image_x.parentNode.removeChild(image_x);
      img.style.display = "block";
    } 
</script>
```

I want it to have an infinite amount of clicks and not just a one and done button, how do I do it?

Comment: Maybe it stops working because your whole script crashes. Any error in the console?

Comment: You need to show us your HTML or where you call your functions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your button won't show the image again after you hide it was because of this line

```
image_x.parentNode.removeChild(image_x);
```

You are removing the element out of the page completely so when you select it again with

```
var img = document.getElementById('tierlist')
```

it won't be able to find the item.

Suggestion: Setting the display style of the item to "none" when you want to hide it and set it to "block" when you want to display it.
Example:

```js
function toggle(){
  var txtDiv = document.getElementById('tierlist');
  if(txtDiv.style.display == "none"){
    txtDiv.style.display = "block"
  } else{
    txtDiv.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="tierlist">Hello</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">Show/hide</button>
```